# Don't know how to reference other scene into script

Tags: godot

I can't link SliceAndCoagulatorScene to the script to set its visible to false I've tried `get_node`, `$res://...`

```
extends Node2D

onready var main_scene = get_node(".")
onready var SliceAndCoagulatorScene = get_node("_________")



func _ready():
    
    main_scene.visible = true
```

This is what I would like to put after :

`SliceAndCoagulatorScene.visible = false`

How could I do this, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

For clarity: A `res://` path does not exist in the scene tree, it exists in the virtual file system. As such, you cannot access it from `get_node`. Because `get_node` works on the scene tree, thus you need to load and instantiate the scene in the scene tree first.

If you have added the scene to the scene tree in the editor, then it will load it and instantiate it for you, and there will be a path you can put in `get_node`... But it will not be a `res://` path, because, again, a `res://` path exists in the virtual file system.

You give `res://` paths to `load` (or `load_interactive`, see [Background loading](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/io/background_loading.htm), or `change_scene`), not to `get_node`.

Now, either you are trying to target a scene that is loaded or one that isn't.

---

If your other scene is not loaded, you need to load it (`load` or `load_interactive`) which gives you a `PackedScene`, instantiate it (`instance`) which gives you a `Node`. At which point you have a reference, go ahead an use it. You probably want to add to the scene tree (e.g. `add_child`).

For example, here we attach the new scene to the root (which may or may not be what you want, in particular in the face of changing scenes, but that is another topic):

```
func _ready():
    var packed_scene = load("res://something.tscn")
    var scene_node = packed_scene.instance()
    var root = get_tree().get_root()
    root.add_child(scene_node)
    scene_node.visible = false # or whatever
```

I will suggest to use a `PackedScene` export:

```
export(PackedScene) var packed_scene
onready var scene_node = load(packed_scene).instance()

func _ready():
    var root = get_tree().get_root()
    root.add_child(scene_node)
    scene_node.visible = false # or whatever
```

Then in the inspector panel you will see a new property "Packed Scene" (Godot auto capitalizes the name) where you can specify the scene from the file system. Plus, if you move scenes in the file system in the editor, the editor will update the path for you.

Note: you may or may not want to add them to `get_tree().get_root()`. Other options include adding it to `get_tree().get_current_scene()`, `get_owner()`, `get_parent()` and to `self`.

---

On the other hand, both your scenes are already loaded in the scene tree. In which case, there is a path from one node to the other, which you can put in `get_node`. If your target scene is not a child, you probably want to go up a few levels with `..`. However, I would advice against hard-coding such path.

Instead, you will get a lot of leverage of the following:

```
export(NodePath) var target_scene
onready var scene_node = get_node(target_scene)
```

Then in the inspector panel you will see a new property "Target Scene" where you can specify where in the scene tree the node you want to access is. Plus, if you move the nodes around in the scene tree in the editor, it will update the path for you.

Then you can do:

```
func _ready():
    scene_node.visible = false # or whatever
```

Note: If you don't know if the scene is loaded. You might be interested in using `find_node`. `Control` also provide a `get_node_or_null`.

Comment: How do you type the scene_node if you statically load the resource? For example if I have `var packed = preload("res://otherScene.tscn")` and then in `_ready` I do `var other = packed.initialize(1)` how do I get InteliSense for the `other` variable in gdscript? So that it sees all the `#export` variables and functions from the `otherScene`?

Comment: Preloading a scene fully type safe would be `const Scene:PacketScene = preload("res://scene.tscn")`. However, Godot won't get the type of the instance. So, if the root node of the scene does not have does not have a script, I would use the node type explicitly, e.g. `var other:Node2D = Scene.initialize()`, if it has a script with a `class_name` I can use that `var other:MyClassName = Scene.initialize()`, otherwise I need to also load the script: `const SceneClass:GDScript = preload("res://scene.gd")` so I can say `var other:SceneClass = Scene.initialize()`.

Comment: @SkillGG  Ah, but, due to a bug, you might want to use the `as` syntax: `var other := Scene.initialize() as MyClassName` or `var other := Scene.initialize() as SceneClass` - you can also use it on the preloads: `const Scene := preload("res://scene.tscn") as PacketScene` and `const SceneClass := preload("res://scene.gd") as GDScript`. I do not know why the other syntax does not give you full autocompletion (as I said it is a bug, but I don't know the details), but using `as` will. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76973611/402022

Comment: I learned about `class_name` while searching the net, but it still wouldn't work. But after adding the `as` keyword after `initialize()` it finally worked! Thanks