# What does the "as" keyword do in GDscript? How is it different from just declaring a variable?

Tags: godot, gdscript

How is this:

`var grenade = grenade_scene.instantiate() as RigidBody2D`

different from:

`var grenade: RigidBody2d = grenade_scene.instantiate()`

The engine doesn't autocomplete any functions inside RigidBody2d when I declare it with a colon(:), but when I use the "as" keyword it detects the functions.

I expected that both lines of code would be the same.

Answer (score 5):

The `as` operator casts the instance to the given type, it returns `null` if the type is incompatible.

---

```
var grenade = grenade_scene.instantiate() as RigidBody2D
```

Here you are declaring a variable with no given type.

And you are initializing it with the result of `grenade_scene.instantiate()` casted to `RigidBody2D` if it is of that type or derived, or `null` otherwise.

---

You could also do this:

```
var grenade := grenade_scene.instantiate() as RigidBody2D
```

Here you are declaring a variable of type `RigidBody2D`. The type is implicit, as Godot infers it from the value you use to initialize the variable.

And - just as before - you are initializing it with the result of `grenade_scene.instantiate()` casted to `RigidBody2D` if it is of that type or derived, or `null` otherwise.

---

In either of the above cases, you could check for `null` or using `is_instanc_valid` to know if the cast failed:

```
if not is_instance_valid(grenade):
    push_error("invalid grenade scene")
```

If you know it is the correct type, you might opt to omit such checks, however be aware that if you change the type you will get `null` and no error or warning, which sometimes might be hard to debug.

---

On the other hand...

```
var grenade: RigidBody2d = grenade_scene.instantiate()
```

Here you are declaring a variable of type `RigidBody2d` (sic). This time the type is explicit.

Now, if the type of `grenade_scene.instantiate()` is not compatible you will get a runtime error.

This is arguably better from the stand point of debuggability.

Sadly, you do not get *full* autocompletion of members with this form at the time of writing. This appears to be a bug. *This seems to be fixed for the upcoming Godot 4.3*

Answer (score 0):

`var grenade = grenade_scene.instantiate() as RigidBody2D`: Uses the as keyword to explicitly cast the instantiated object to type RigidBody2D, providing better autocompletion support.

`var grenade: RigidBody2D = grenade_scene.instantiate()`: Explicitly declares the type of the grenade variable as RigidBody2D, but type inference might not work as well for autocompletion.